# Ruby On Rails with MemSQL. Table `schema_migrations` must either have a PRIMARY or SHARD key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, singlestore

I am currently using Rails (`4.2.0`) with MySQL.
I want to setup MemSQL with my Rails application.

I followed the tutorial to get MemSQL working on OSX inside a docker container. It works fine.
I have set up the MemSQL IP inside my `database.yml`.

I successfully ran `rake db:create`.
However when running `rake db:migrate`, I get the following error:

```
> rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Distributed tables must either have a PRIMARY or SHARD key. Visit http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/concepts/porting-apps/ for more information: CREATE TABLE `schema_migrations` (`version` varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB

Mysql2::Error: Distributed tables must either have a PRIMARY or SHARD key. Visit http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/concepts/porting-apps/ for more information
```

I guess I could, somehow,  edit the `db/schema.rb` file and try to alter the `schema_migrations` table. But id doesn't seems to be a good solution as it will be regenerated each time I update my tables.

What should I do to get over with this issue ?

## EDIT

This error occurs with a brand new rails project.
I did the following:

- create a new rails project
- add mysql2 gem
- configure database.yml to memsql ip
- add devise gem
- add user table with devise
- rake db:create
- rake db:migrate (result of this command below)

Content of schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150729143850) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

## EDIT II

This questions is more for Rails Developer than MemSQL expert.
 - MemSQL NEED a primary or shard key for each table it handles.
 - However Rails does not define one for its `schema_migrations` table.
This issue, brings me the following question:
**How to tweak Rails to have it define a Primary or Shard key for its `schema_migrations` table ?**

Comment: In this case, `rake db:create` succeeds because it's simply creating the database. `rake db:migrate` tries creates the tables, which is where it fails. As @Jerry mentioned below, you need to have (at least) a primary key to create a distributed table in MemSQL.

Can you share the contents of your `schema.rb`?

Comment: You're right. I posted these, as two separate step to show that the connection was successfully established. I edited my post to reflect your question.

Answer (score 0):

Memsql is a distributed database. This probably means it would require some form of sharding (horizontal partitioning - logical of course!) implemented. By default, Memsql uses the primary key as the shard key if not explicitly specified. It seems that in your case, there are tables that are missing a primary key and shard keys have not been specified. Hence you would have to either set primary keys for those tables or explicitly choose a shard key column. See the [Memsql documentation](http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/concepts/porting-apps/) for more details.

Comment: You are right Jerry. However the problem do not come from my tables (as you can see in my post EDIT). But from the way Rails handles migrations. It uses a `schema_migrations ` table that do not have a Primary nor a Shard key. So my post is more about how to "fix" rails, in a "clean" way.